# Confusion about the WelcomePage middleware using

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I have the application Pipeline set up in the following manner:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.Use(async (context,next) => {

        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Custom MiddleWare");
        await next.Invoke();
    });

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseWelcomePage(new WelcomePageOptions
    {
        Path = "/Welcome"
    });
    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(Environment.NewLine+"Greetings");
    });
}
```

When i go to page the  `http://localhost:port/` i get the following output:

> Custom MiddleWare
>
> Greetings

But the welcome page at `http://localhost:port/welcome` does not work and gives an error:

> This site can’t be reached

Now if I modify the pipeline like this it gets fixed:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseWelcomePage(new WelcomePageOptions
    {
        Path = "/Welcome"
    });

    app.Use(async (context, next) => {

        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Custom MiddleWare");
        await next.Invoke();
    });

    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(Environment.NewLine+"Greetings");
    });
}
```

I am trying to understand the reason why the `UseWelcomePage` middleware did not get called in first scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that first middleware writes to response body

```
 await context.Response.WriteAsync("Custom MiddleWare");
```

This actually starts the response and so WelcomePage middleware fails with an exception as cannot add headers, that you may see in logs:

```
 An unhandled exception has occurred: Headers are read-only, response has already started.
System.InvalidOperationException: Headers are read-only, response has already started.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.FrameHeaders.ThrowHeadersReadOnlyException()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.FrameHeaders.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHeaderDictionary.set_Item(String key, StringValues value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpResponse.set_ContentType(String value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.RazorViews.WelcomePage.<ExecuteAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Comment: @ExpertNovice: looks like the same problem. I had added DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware and got the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware:Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request`

Comment: Middleware should not write to the response and then call next. This confuses subsequent components because they can no longer set the status code, add headers, etc..